# How to use synchronized method to prevent race condition in if statement?

Tags: java, multithreading, conditional-statements, synchronized

I'm trying to prevent race condition in my code,
At one code block if statement checking a condition with a method (if a variable is null or not), and end of the code block (after some major operations) that variable changes, it's not NULL anymore.

If two thread run that block at the same time, one of them finishing the block and after that other one getting exception because of ID/Value already written(exist) to the datamap by first thread.
The second thread need to wait for the first one finish its job.
And after the that waiting, variable is not NULL anymore , and second thread will not run the code block, won't get exception.

Example code (JAVA):

```
SOTable testtable= SOTable.getInstance();

if (testtable.findvalue(ID) == null){

// A lot of if statements here...
// At the last of the code block:

testtable.insert(ID,data);

// testtable.findvalue(ID) not equal NULL any more

}

// findvalue method
public SOData findvalue(String ID) {      
      SOData  testdata = null;
      synchronized (lock) {
         testdata = (SOData)dataMap.getValue(ID);
      }
      return testdata; // If ID not match returns NULL
   }
```

Do you think using of "synchronized (lock)" here can prevent that situation ?

Thanks

Comment: The synchonization needs to be held across the lookup and insert, since the entire "insert if not already present" needs to be treated as atomic.

Comment: `dataMap` may provides some atomic operations which may be help. Or you can use db lock or db key to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

`synchronized` will help with controlling access by multiple threads within a single process.

However, slapping on `synchronized` isn't always right, and can cause more problems if it's not right.  Since it looks like you're dealing with an external persistence layer (a table), there's the possibility of a different process (either on the same machine or a different machine) that is making an update - `synchronized` won't help with that.

You need to debug further & determine the root cause of the issue - what is it that's making the competing modification - before determining if using `synchronized` is the right solution.